# Connected sub set

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let X be a topological space, and A sub set

how to prove that the following are equivalent:

1) A is connected

2) if A is decomposed into two open sets M and N such that $A=M\cup N$ and $$  (\overline{M}\cap N)\cup(M\cap \overline{N})=\emptyset   $$  then $N=\emptyset$ or $M=\emptyset$

Thank you

Comment: What is your definition for a topological space to be connected? What you have written is the definition I'm used to seeing.

Comment: On another note: having been a member of the site for well over a year, you should provide some evidence of an attempt (or related definitions, etc.).

Comment: any definition I proved that the 4 definitions are equivalent

Comment: I am saying that what you are asking is exactly the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space) I'm used to seeing. I also know the definition that the only clopen subsets are the whole set and the empty set (you need to specify *exactly* what your definition is).

Comment: but the definition is for the whole space and here we work on a sub set ??

Comment: @clayton i read an other time and in the book separate means $$(\overline{M}\cap N)\cup(M\cap \overline{N})=\emptyset$$

Comment: A subset $A$ of $X$ is connected iff it is connected in the subspace topology, by definition. There is no separate definition for the whole space or a subset of it.

Comment: so this is false? see https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://perso.eleves.ens-rennes.fr/people/Antoine.Diez/connexite.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjgu-2onMbhAhVJ8OAKHdnBACQQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw1kD-QbagUwKkMRK0JcvkAw

Comment: @Henno see proposition 1.10

Comment: 1.6 is exactly what I said. Just the definition of connected space when given the subspace topology.

Comment: but how to prove propo1.10?

Answer (score 1):

On definitions: Following the link in the comments to the original definitions the OP is using (namely [this French text](http://perso.eleves.ens-rennes.fr/people/Antoine.Diez/connexite.pdf)) we see that $A$ is called a connected subset if it is connected in the subspace topology and a space is called connected whenever we write it as a disjoint union of two closed (or two open) subsets, one of them is empty.

Now suppose $A$ is connected, and write $A= M \cup N$ where $\overline{M}\cap N= M \cap \overline{N}=\emptyset$ (so called separated sets). Note that this already implies that $M$ and $N$ are disjoint.

Then $M$ is closed in $A$ (in its subspace topology), because if $x \in A$ lies in the closure of $M$ (in $A$), $x \in N$ is impossible (as $N$ misses $\overline{M}$) and so $x \in A=M \cup N$ implies $x \in M$.
Similarly $N$ is closed in $A$ as well.

But then $M \cup N$ is (in $A$) just a decomposition of $A$ into two disjoint closed sets and so one of them is empty. Done.

The reverse is also clear, because if we write $A$ as a union of $C \cup D$, disjoint relatively open sets, $C$ and $D$ are separated in $X$ (if $x \in D$, $x \in U \cap A=D$ for some open subset $U$ of $X$, and this $U$ witnesses that $U \cap C = \emptyset$, so that $x \notin \overline{C}$; that $\overline{D} \cap C = \emptyset$ is symmetrical), and so one of them is empty by the assumption on separated sets.

Comment: $\overline{C}$ means the closure of C or the complement of C?

Comment: @PolineSandra the closure.

Comment: please I don't understand how to prove that M is claused?

Comment: @PolineSandra $M$ and $N$ are closed in $A$! The distinction matters.

Comment: Please, C and D are the M and N ? and the idea is to suppose that A is not connected? thank you

Comment: @PolineSandra for the reverse we assume $A$ is not connected and show it’s a union of separated sets, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

A is disconnected iff exists open U,V with
not empty, disjoint U $\cap$ A, V $\cap$ A
and A = (U $\cup$ V) $\cap$ A.  (1)

The disjoint sets are the M,N that decompose A.

Thus A is connected iff for all open U,V, (if
U $\cap$ A, V $\cap$ A are disjoint and A = (U $\cup$ V) $\cap$ A,
then U $\cap$ or V $\cap$ A is empty).

The conclusion follows be negating both sides of (1).

Comment: oh then they mean the complement of M by $\overline{M}$ not the closur? because it is a French book.

Comment: where is M and N here?